# Set background color for <li> but not its child

Tags: html, css

I would like to set one `<li>` of a HTML Lists with background colour.
There are some children inside, but I would like to keep the children without background color (transparent).

```
<ul>
  <li style="background: #fb7171!important;">
    <span>HEADING 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li style="background: transparent!important;">sub-heading A</li>
      <li style="background: transparent!important;">sub-heading B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I do so?

I posted my code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6zvwxva0/

Comment: Move `background-color` to `span` and make it a block element or use `div` instead.

Comment: @Kelvin Low they are already transparent, (you can see the background color of their parent)

Comment: I tried but the area `<span>` is too small. `<li>` filled a whole row and it's what I want. How do I set `<span>` as long as `<li>`? @MohammadUsman

Comment: My background is transparent. I want the children back to transparent but no luck @TimothyGroote

Comment: @KelvinLow As I said, make it a block level element by adding `display: block` or replace `span` with a `div`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zvwxva0/5/)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap each of the `li` contents (the text) in a span or a div.
Apply the background-color to these. In order to the sub-items have a different color, you need to override the parent.

```css
/* First level */
ul li span {
  display: block; /*this makes the span as wide as the li*/
  background-color: #fb7171;
}

/* all children (multiple levels) */
ul ul li span {
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>HEADING 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>sub-heading A</span></li>
      <li><span>sub-heading B</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>HEADING 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>sub-heading A</span></li>
      <li><span>sub-heading B</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you @beerwin very much. I never thought this is workable.

Answer (score 3):

You are going perfectly with your last fiddle code. https://jsfiddle.net/6zvwxva0/6/
you have to add only 'width:100%' in span tag.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span style="background: #fb7171; display:inline-block;width:100%">HEADING 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>sub-heading A</li>
            <li>sub-heading B</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I posted code here also. https://jsfiddle.net/0q541cj2/

Answer (score 1):

there is two approach to fix your problem :

**#1**

you can just set the display:inline for the li like this

```
<ul>
    <li style="background: #fb7171; display:inline;">
        <span>HEADING 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>sub-heading A</li>
            <li>sub-heading B</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**#2**

or you can just set the background on span. the result would be the same

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span style="background: #fb7171; display:inline-block;">HEADING 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>sub-heading A</li>
            <li>sub-heading B</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE**

in the first approach if you want to li be full with you can simply do this :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span style="background: #fb7171!important;display:inline-block;width:100%;">HEADING 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li style="background: transparent!important;">sub-heading A</li>
            <li style="background: transparent!important;">sub-heading B</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

remember that in this situation you should keep those background transparent properties on childrens.

Comment: It's work but too short. I hope it can be as long as a single `<li>`. Is it possible?

Comment: @KelvinLow which one ? first approach or the second one ?

Comment: @KelvinLow you can just set display:inline-block;width:100%; on li and it will result of the full width

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a pseudo element (on the `li` or the `span`) that will behave as a background and easily control its position with top/left/right/bottom:

```css
li.back span {
  position: relative;
}

li.back span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -30px;
  right: -100%;
  background: #fb7171;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="back">
    <span>HEADING 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>sub-heading A</li>
      <li>sub-heading B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="back">
    <span>HEADING 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>sub-heading A</li>
      <li>sub-heading B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why the height 20px is hard coded? what if I increase the span content font-size?

Comment: @NitinDhomse i simply give an example, this can chaned depending on the situation, we can use `1em` for example or anything else ;)

Answer (score 1):

This one will give exact result as you wanted.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span style="background: #fb7171!important;display:inline-block;width:100%;">HEADING 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li style="background: transparent!important;">sub-heading A</li>
            <li style="background: transparent!important;">sub-heading B</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must apply background color to span element in order to get what you wanted. Also I encourage you to use external or internal css over inline css if possible. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6zvwxva0/11/) is an working example.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="item-has-bg">
  <li >
    <span>HEADING 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>sub-heading A</li>
      <li>sub-heading B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.item-has-bg > li > span {
  background-color: #fb7171;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't see anything wrong the OP needs his child li to be transparent and that would be the output